# How to integrate android camera for LibGDX project? (deprecated material..)

Tags: opengl, java, android, libgdx, camera

I'm trying to use the Android camera in LibGDX. I tried using this implementation of the API, which is basically the only you will find on Google.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Integrating-libgdx-and-the-device-camera

However, most of it is deprecated. It uses GL10, and the methods it calls to connect to the camera are stubs. It is not usable, and the API has probably got easier to use since (but I'd rather not look at google documentation when this has probably been made before... or has it? nothing on Google anyway).

So, do I have to make my own implementation, or is there anything available that would make it any easier? Or is the 2013 implementation actually still usable somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LibGDX is pretty actively developed (the last commit being 20 hours since I wrote this), so I highly doubt the 2013 implementation has changed much, if at all; it's highly likely they'd update that section of the wiki if any drastic changes took place. Also, if that's not enough, comment on the wiki post and ask if it's still current. Again, it's rather actively developed, so the response shouldn't take long.

Comment: Sorry, but the code on wiki page https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Integrating-libgdx-and-the-device-camera
does not work on Android 8.1 devices.